# Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 5.0.17 specifically: NU1603

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nuget

For a netstandard2.1-based solution I'd need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.17 specifically, but when I try:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 5.0.17
```

I get:

```
warn : NU1603: BWO.Licensing.Data depends on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 5.0.17) but Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.17 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.7 was resolved.
error: NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.7 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.7 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
```

I've already tried manually downloading the package and adding it to the local package source, without success. How can I enforce version 5.0.17 to be used?

Comment: Can we see `PackageReference`s of your `.csproj` file (of the project you want to reference EFC 5.0.17)?

Comment: I've also tried to manually add these:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.17" />
But without any success.

Comment: Are you using a custom NuGet server/mirror or nuget.org?

Comment: nuget.org, but I also have a local private nuget server...